# Is it justifiable to store redundant data in a RDBMS to simplify queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

For example, if i store a redundant column in one table, i can avoid joining 5 tables in  runtime SQL queries.  In cases such as this, is it justifiable to store redundant data?  My understanding is that it violates the rules of normalization but I'm not a db expert.
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, denormalizing for performance is not in itself an evil, but you need to check first that you cannot optimize the queries that you run against your initial 3NF design to give you reasonable timing.

Here is a [link](http://www.25hoursaday.com/weblog/CommentView.aspx?guid=cc0e740c-a828-4b9d-b244-4ee96e2fad4b) to a nice article suggesting that reduction in the number of joins is a common (and good) reason to denormalize.

Answer (score 2):

I will only say that I've only broken normalization rules once (that I'm aware of :-|) and I've regretted it ever since. It gave me about 15% more speed but added all kinds of extra maintenance code and fragility to the system.

I would look into whether you can't speed up the joins by better indexing, or giving the DBMS a chance to predefine a query plan somehow (i.e. whatever that takes in your DBMS), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does violate normalization rules.

But you're a big boy.  You ought to know the rules and when it's appropriate to break them.

Five tables aren't are lot.  What data do you have to tell you that normalization is going to break your app, and that denormalization will fix it?  (I'm guessing none either way.)

Query speed is affected by more than JOINs: indexing, WHERE clauses, etc.

Normalization rules come with certain benefits and costs.  You ought to know what you're giving up before you go that route.

Answer (score 1):

It indeed violates the [third normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) (**3NF**). However, sometimes, it can be justifiable, in favour of **performance**. Collect some usage statistics of your database, and see if that query is taking too long, or if it's being used very frequently, and see if denormalizing it can be of benefit to your system.

Obviously, with this denormalized structure, you'll have to take care of other potential issues. For example, you need to maintain **consistency** between your redundant columns and the ones that are stored in your other 5 tables.

Also, when inserting data, you have to store it in **two** different places, in the denormalized table, as well as the other *original* tables.